# CNN learning stagnation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

I have created a simulation of the CNN I am trying to use on video data set.
I set the test data to all one single image on all frames for positive examples and 0 for negative examples. I thought this would learn very quickly. But it does not move at all.
Using current versions of Keras & Tensorflow on Windows 10 64bit.

First question, is my logic wrong? Should I expect the learning of this test data to quickly reach high accuracy?

Is there something wrong with my model or parameters? I have been trying a number of changes but still get the same problem.

Is the sample size (56) too small?

```
# testing  feature extraction model. 
import time
import numpy as np, cv2
import sys
import os
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D

from keras.optimizers import SGD,rmsprop, adam

from keras import regularizers
from keras.initializers import Constant

from keras.models import Model

#set gpu options
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=.99, allocator_type = 'BFC') 
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True, gpu_options=gpu_options))
config = tf.ConfigProto()

batch_size = 5
num_classes = 1
epochs = 50
nvideos = 56
nframes = 55
nchan = 3
nrows = 480
ncols = 640

#load any single image, resize if needed
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\david\\Documents\\AutonomousSS\\single frame.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img,(640,480))

x_learn = np.random.randint(0,255,(nvideos,nframes,nrows,ncols,nchan),dtype=np.uint8)
y_learn = np.array([[1],[1],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],
                    [1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],
                    [1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[0],[0],[1],[1],
                    [1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],
                    [0],[1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],
                    [1],[1],[0],[1],[0],[0]],np.uint8)

#each sample, each frame is either the single image for postive examples or 0 for negative examples.

for i in range (nvideos):
    if y_learn[i] == 0 : 
        x_learn[i]=0
    else:
        x_learn[i,:nframes]=img



#build model     
m_loss = 'mean_squared_error'
m_opt = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
m_met = 'acc' 


model = Sequential()

# 1st layer group
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3,3), activation='relu',padding="same", name="conv1a", strides=(3, 3, 3),
                 kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
                 trainable=False,
                 input_shape=(nframes,nrows,ncols,nchan)))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv1b", activation="relu"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(padding="valid", trainable=False, pool_size=(1, 5, 5), name="pool1", strides=(2, 2, 2)))


# 2nd layer group
model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv2a", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv2b", activation="relu"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(padding="valid", trainable=False, pool_size=(1, 5, 5), name="pool2", strides=(2, 2, 2)))

# 3rd layer group
model.add(Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv3a", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv3b", activation="relu"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(padding="valid", trainable=False, pool_size=(1, 5, 5), name="pool3", strides=(2, 2, 2)))

# 4th layer group
model.add(Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv4a", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), trainable=False, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="same", name="conv4b", activation="relu"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(padding="valid", trainable=False, pool_size=(1, 5, 5), name="pool4", strides=(2, 2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten(name='flatten',trainable=False))

model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu', trainable=True,name='den0'))

model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax',name='den1'))
print (model.summary())

#compile model
model.compile(loss=m_loss,
              optimizer=m_opt,
              metrics=[m_met])
print ('compiled')


#set callbacks
from keras import backend as K
K.set_learning_phase(0) #set learning phase
tb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=sample_root_path+'logs', histogram_freq=0,
                          write_graph=True, write_images=False)
tb.set_model(model)
reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.2,verbose=1,
              patience=2, min_lr=0.000001)
reduce_lr.set_model(model)
ear_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0, patience=4, verbose=1, mode='auto')
ear_stop.set_model(model)


#fit

history = model.fit(x_learn, y_learn,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr,tb, ear_stop],
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    shuffle = True,
                    epochs=epochs)


score = model.evaluate(x_learn, y_learn, batch_size=batch_size)
print(str(model.metrics_names) + ": " + str(score))
```

As usual, thanks for any and all help.

added output...

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1a (Conv3D)              (None, 19, 160, 214, 32)  2624      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1b (Conv3D)              (None, 19, 160, 214, 32)  27680     
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 10, 78, 105, 32)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2a (Conv3D)              (None, 10, 78, 105, 128)  110720    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2b (Conv3D)              (None, 10, 78, 105, 128)  442496    
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 5, 37, 51, 128)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3a (Conv3D)              (None, 5, 37, 51, 256)    884992    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3b (Conv3D)              (None, 5, 37, 51, 256)    1769728   
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 3, 17, 24, 256)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4a (Conv3D)              (None, 3, 17, 24, 512)    3539456   
_________________________________________________________________
conv4b (Conv3D)              (None, 3, 17, 24, 512)    7078400   
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 2, 7, 10, 512)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 71680)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
den0 (Dense)                 (None, 512)               36700672  
_________________________________________________________________
den1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 50,557,281
Trainable params: 36,701,185
Non-trainable params: 13,856,096
_________________________________________________________________
None
compiled
Train on 50 samples, validate on 6 samples
Epoch 1/50
50/50 [==============================] - 20s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/50
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/50
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/50
45/50 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5111 - acc: 0.4889
Epoch 00003: reducing learning rate to 0.00020000000949949026.
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/50
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/50
45/50 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5111 - acc: 0.4889
Epoch 00005: reducing learning rate to 4.0000001899898055e-05.
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/50
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/50
45/50 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4889 - acc: 0.5111
Epoch 00007: reducing learning rate to 8.000000525498762e-06.
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 9/50
50/50 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00008: early stopping
56/56 [==============================] - 12s    
['loss', 'acc']: [0.50000001516725334, 0.5000000127724239]
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your aim in general, your final data that you want to train on and especially why you try to train on a single image? And since you set all your layers to not be trainable (apart from your last dense layer): Do you load any pretrained weights? I don´t see you importing a Keras Application like VGG or Inception or loading any weights otherwise.

Comment: The ultimate aim is to train for a certain motion. That is a sequence of movement between frames. The test above is just one test example. I get the same behavior with positive examples  being 1) all frames ones, 2) frames are random and 3) frames are real video sequences. I don't think built in Keras apps will help.

Comment: Ok and thanks for clarifying some points. As far as I understand you want to finetune a pretrained model. If so: How do you load the weights? A Keras Application is exactly one good way to do that. See for example this tutorial from Keras: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html Otherwise your network doesn´t learn anything because almost all layer are set to non trainable. From your code: `…trainable=False…`

Comment: I get resource issue with training more layers.

Answer (score 0):

Your layers are set to `trainable=False`(apart from the last dense layer). Therefore your CNN cannot learn. In addition you won´t be able to train just on a single sample.

If you run into performance issues on your GPU switch to CPU or AWS or reduce your image size.

Comment: I may not be clear, I want to train a 3d network. The keras apps are for 2d images so I can;t see how their predefined values could help.

Comment: Ok. Then again: Why do you set 95% of your ConvNet to trainable=False?

Comment: I was following a methodology described in a recent research paper. I have tried lowering the data size and adding more layers to be trainable. did not make a difference.

Comment: What happens if you set all layers to be trainable? Otherwise only the random initialization values will flow from the first convolutional layers to the rest of the network and you don´t have any learned low level features that the next layers can stack upon.

Comment: Trained all layers, no change in result.

Comment: I changed the loss function to categorical_crossentropy and metric to categorical_accuracy. It is trying to learn now.